# Adding javascript to a new form in a form Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

How do i add javascript to the form library new form, since i published infopath form as default form page.

I am using sharepoint 2013 and infopath 2013 to customize the form. Is there any way to add script/ jquery to theform.

IS Sharepoint designer is the only option?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a javascript file using the content web part.

You can do this by

**Edit page -> Add web part -> Media and content -> Content editor -> Add**

Edit the source of the web part and add the following code into it:

```
​<script src="/sites/subsite/list/SiteAssets/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add the js file under Site Assets using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, check the link out below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/03/18/introduction-to-programming-in-infopath-2010.aspx

its too big to go through to post here! bottom line is you need to add codebehind and add

```
private string BindScript(string ScriptUrl, bool PickFromSiteCollection)
{
    if (PickFromSiteCollection)
        ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url, ScriptUrl);
    else
        ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, ScriptUrl);
    return string.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}""></script>", ScriptUrl);
}
```

call the above method in an event that you require (override) like onload or onsubmit ect

```
writer.Write(BindScript("/_layouts/1033/js/jquery.min.js", true));
```

Comment: sorry ali...i couldnot use the code in the infopath since client is not allowed to do so....is there any solution apart from this

Comment: when you say not allowed to do so how do you mean exactly? asin hasnt get the right privligaes to run code?

Comment: Ali...i have to do jquery in submit action....if so...i need to use edit code option...which will take me to custom code...which i am not suppose to do as per client requirement....

Comment: tell me if so any solution....or let me know if i m not right

Comment: add content editor and edit in html.put your javascript there.